# Getting The bean 'authenticationManagerBuilder', defined in class path resource ... could not be registered

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Im trying to implement authentication with Spring boot 3 like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz

                .requestMatchers("/webjars/**", "/resources/**", "/css/**", "/images/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated()).formLogin((form) -> form.loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("email").permitAll())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService UserDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService();
    }

    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public void authenticationManagerBuilder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authConfiguration) throws Exception {
        authConfiguration.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
    
}
```

and getting this error :

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> The bean 'authenticationManagerBuilder', defined in class path
> resource [com/test/admin/security/WebSecurityConfig.class], could not
> be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configuration/AuthenticationConfiguration.class]
> and overriding is disabled.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

from this document :

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

they've changed the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. so ive changed this :

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    return auth.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

to this :

```
    @Bean
    public void authenticationManagerBuilder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authConfiguration) throws Exception {
        authConfiguration.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
```

and now getting error.

also if i change it to this :

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

my error goes away?!

Comment: Why you want to create AuthenticationManagerBuilder bean?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal Exatcly that was the problem. after the switching to AuthenticationManager problem goes away.

Comment: ok you mean to say problem is resolved now?

Comment: ty , yes the problem is gone atm and ive updated my question with edit.